# Cannot feed value of shape (0,) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 224, 224)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

```
i have been trying to execute this machine learning code and am consistently getting reshaping error below is my script.i suspect this section is the one having issues.


with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)
   saver=tf.train.Saver()
   merged =tf.summary.merge_all()
   writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs',sess.graph)
   for i in range(1,epoch):
        batch_ss =read_images[j:batch+j]
        labels_ss =labels[j:batch+j]

        j+=batch
        if j+batch>=len(read_images):
            j=0

        feed_dict_train = {x:batch_ss,
                           y_true:labels_ss}

        summary_loss,loss=sess.run([summary_COST_loss,cost],feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
```

when i run the code i get this error.i suspect the issue is in the feed_dict but i have been debugging it for days without success.what might be my mistake.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-57c90aa9f9ce> in <module>()
     15                            y_true:labels_ss}
     16 
---> 17         summary_loss,loss=sess.run([summary_COST_loss,cost],feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1147                              'which has shape %r' %
   1148                              (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name,
-> 1149                               str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   1150           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
   1151             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0,) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 224, 224)'
```

the full code look like this.i have tried to play also with placeholders but i cant figure out where the problem is.the program works well util i try to load training data.someone to help me please

```
!!alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5
!pip install q keras==2.1.6
!pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.14

import cv2
import numpy
import glob
import pylab as plt
import tensorflow as tf

#convolution layer 1
filter_size1=3 # convolutional filters are 3x3 pixels
num_filters1= 32 #there are 16 of these filters
#convolutional layer 2
filter_size2=3 # convolutional filters are 3x3 pixels
num_filters2= 32 #there are 16 of these filters
#convolution layer 3
filter_size3=3
num_filters3=64

#fully connected layer
fc_size=128 #number of neurns in fully connected layer
num_channels=3
img_size =128
img_size_flat= img_size*img_size*num_channels

img_shape=[374,388]
epoch=500
batch=20
j=0

folders = glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/ester/DB1_B/*')

len(folders)

imagenames_list = []
labels =[]
imagenames_list=[]
count = 0

for folder in folders:
        for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.tif'):
            imagenames_list.append(f)
            labels.append(count)
        count+=1
read_images=[]
Tensor_input=[]

for image in imagenames_list:
        read_images.append(cv2.imread(image,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))

labels=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(
                 labels,
                  num_classes=4
                 )

def new_weights(shape):
        return tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

def new_biases(length):
        return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]))

def new_conv_layer(
                input,
                num_input_channels,
                filter_size,
                num_filters,
                use_pooling = True
                ):
        shape = [ filter_size,filter_size,num_input_channels,num_filters]

        weights = new_weights(shape=shape)

        biases = new_biases(length=num_filters)

        layer =tf.nn.conv2d(
                          input=input,
                          filter= weights,
                          strides=[1,1,1,1],
                          padding='SAME'
                        )
        layer += biases
    
        if use_pooling:
            layer= tf.nn.max_pool( value=layer,
                               #input=layer,#modified from value
                               ksize=[1,2,2,1],
                               strides=[1,2,2,1],
                               padding='SAME',
                             )

        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
     


        return layer,weights

def flatten_layer(layer):
        layer_shape = layer.get_shape()

        num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()
        layer_flat =tf.reshape(layer,[-1 , num_features])

        return layer_flat,num_features

def new_fc_layer(
                 input,
                 num_inputs,
                 num_outputs,
                 use_relu=True
                 ):
        weights= new_weights(shape=[num_inputs,num_outputs])
        biases=new_biases(length=num_outputs)
        layer =tf.matmul(input,weights) + biases
        if use_relu:
            layer =tf.nn.relu(layer)

        return layer

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

x= tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,374, 388],name='x')

x_image = tf.reshape(x,[-1, 224,224,1])

print(x_image)

y_true = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10],name='y_true') 
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true,axis=1)

layer_conv1,weights_conv1 =new_conv_layer(input=x_image,
                                          num_input_channels=1,
                                          num_filters=num_filters1,
                                          filter_size=filter_size1,
                                          use_pooling=True
                                          )

layer_conv2,weights_conv2 =new_conv_layer(input=layer_conv1,
                                          num_input_channels=num_filters1,
                                          filter_size =filter_size2,
                                          num_filters=num_filters2,
                                          use_pooling= True)

print(layer_conv1)

print(layer_conv2)

layer_flat,num_features =flatten_layer(layer_conv2)

layer_fc1 = new_fc_layer(input=layer_flat,
                         num_inputs=num_features,
                         num_outputs=10,
                         use_relu=True)

print(layer_fc1)

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc1)

summary_d_x_hist =tf.summary.histogram('y_pred',y_pred)

y_pred_cls =tf.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=layer_fc1,
                                                      labels=y_true)
#cross_entropy=tf.compat.v1.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
   # labels, logits=layer_conv1, axis=None, name=None, dim=None
#)
#cross_entropy=tf.exp(logits=layer_conv1) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(logits=layer_conv1), axis)

summary_d_loss =tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy',cross_entropy)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
summary_COST_loss =tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)

print(summary_d_loss)
print(cost)
print(summary_COST_loss)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls,y_true_cls)

print(correct_prediction)

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
summary_accuracy=tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)

print(accuracy)
print(summary_accuracy)

#optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-2).minimize(cost)
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Initializing the variables
#init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init=tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(init)
       saver=tf.train.Saver()
       merged =tf.summary.merge_all()
       writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs',sess.graph)
       for i in range(1,epoch):
            batch_ss =read_images[j:batch+j]
            labels_ss =labels[j:batch+j]

            j+=batch
            if j+batch>=len(read_images):
                j=0

            feed_dict_train = {x:batch_ss,
                           y_true:labels_ss}

            summary_loss,loss=sess.run([summary_COST_loss,cost],feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
            summary_hist,prediction =sess.run([summary_d_x_hist,y_pred],feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
            print (loss)
            sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict=feed_dic
            writer.add_summary(summary_acc,global_step=i)t_train)
            summary_acc,acc = sess.run([summary_accuracy,accuracy],feed_dict_train)
            if i%2==0:
              acc =sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
              msg ="optimization iteration:{0:>6},Train Accuracy:{1:>6.1%}"
              print(msg.format(i + 1 , acc))
            saver.save(sess,'./logs/model.ckpt',i) 
            writer.add_summary(summary_loss,global_step=i)
            writer.add_summary(summary_hist,global_step=i)
```

Comment: here is the full code

Comment: Where do you define `summary_COST_loss` and `cost`?

Comment: summary_d_loss =tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy',cross_entropy)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
summary_COST_loss =tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)

Comment: below  layer_fc1